# sympy.integrate: TypeError: a is not an integer

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to integrate this expression:

```
import sympy as sy

def Bra_H_Ket():

   a0=sy.Symbol('a0')
   r=sy.Symbol('r')

   psi=1/r*sy.sin(r)*sy.exp(-(a0*r))
   H_Psi=-1/2*sy.diff(psi,r,r)-1/r*psi
   print("H*Psi:")
   print(H_Psi)
   print
   print("Psi*H*Psi:")
   Psi_H_Psi=4*pi*psi*H_Psi*r**2
   print(Psi_H_Psi)
   print
   Bra_H_Ket=sy.integrate(Psi_H_Psi,(r,-sy.oo,3))
   print("Bra_H_Ket:")
   print(Bra_H_Ket)
   print
```

but I got this error:

```
<ipython-input-4-b7c2f227f24d> in <module>()
----> 1 Bra_H_Ket()

<ipython-input-3-57b2347da6cd> in Bra_H_Ket()
     15    print(Psi_H_Psi)
     16 
---> 17    Bra_H_Ket=sy.integrate(Psi_H_Psi, (r, -sy.oo ,3))
     18 
     19    print("Bra_H_Ket:")

[...]

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\integrals\transforms.py in _rewrite_gamma(f, s, a, b)
    668                 newc = c/p
    669                 if not a.is_Integer:
--> 670                     raise TypeError("a is not an integer")
    671                 for k in range(p):
    672                     gammas += [(newa, newc + k/p)]

TypeError: a is not an integer
```

Also it takes quite some time to calculate some integrals (symbolic in my case), so any suggestions that can help because I have many integrals like that.

Comment: It appears you can't use the negative lower infinity as the lower bound. If your function is symmetric, or you can somehow rewrite it with an infinite upper bound instead, it will likely work (see [this documentation section](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/g-functions.html), which is one of the integration types attempted under the hood, but only works for a positive infinite upper bound, apparently).

Comment: sometimes python is not able to calculate some big integrals so any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in SymPy. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8882. I couldn't find a good workaround.